# Rewriting System for Python L-System

Tags: python, string, list, rewriting, rhino3d

I have the following working code for Python I produced. It´s a rewriting system based on Lindenmayer. The Output C is: `+-LF+RFR+FL-F-+RF-LFL-FR+F+RF-LFL-FR+-F-LF+RFR+FL-+` which I can interpret to draw a space-filling curve. C is the starting letter and the process is performed n times.

```
C = 'L'
n = 2
Code = {ord('L'):'+RF-LFL-FR+',
ord('R'):'-LF+RFR+FL-'}

while n:
    C = C.translate(Code)
    n -=1

print C
```

Now I want, that the code is written automatically from a list. For example I have the list `R=[['L', '+RF-LFL-FR+'], ['R', '-LF+RFR+FL-']]` which should be automatically inserted in the code, so I can use it furthermore. The first element of every sub-list should be inserted in the `ord()` method and the second after the colon. Any suggestions?

I found a way via list comprehension. The List R is `L=+RF-LFL-FR+, R=-LF+RFR+FL-`. Now I ask if theres a more efficient way to get to the code?

```
R = ['L=+RF-LFL-FR+','R=-LF+RFR+FL-']
A = 'L'

for i in range(0,len(R)):
    R[i]=R[i].split('=')

print R

Start = []
Rule = []

for i in range(0,len(R)):
    Start.append(R[i][0])
    Rule.append(R[i][1])

#mapping via list comprehension
while n:
    A=''.join([Rule[Start.index(i)] if i in Start else i for i in A])
    n -=1

print A
```

Comment: Did you test your sample code? It does not execute. How is variable A initialized?

Comment: And why is the first attempt not feasible for you? You can convert the input list into a dictionary like this (python3): `Code = dict((ord(key), value) for (key, value) in dict(R).items())`, where `R=[['L', '+RF-LFL-FR+'], ['R', '-LF+RFR+FL-']]`.

Comment: Hey! I forgot to mention, that I have an "outer" input which defines A and R. I'm programming in Grasshopper for Rhino3D, where you can use external inputs. I inserted the two missing variables in the code.

Comment: I'm a really newbie and I have to look up everything I want to programm, so the most obvious things I don't recognize sometimes. I tried your code and it's working perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: I tested both codes about speed, and the one I found is a bit faster.

Comment: Have a look at my extended answer below. I found that my answer was a bit faster than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be working for you. The code runs on python3.

```
def fun1(n):
    axiom = 'L'
    rules = ['L=+RF-LFL-FR+','R=-LF+RFR+FL-']

    # Convert the rules into a translation table.
    rules = [ r.split('=') for r in rules ]
    table = dict((ord(key), value) for (key, value) in dict(rules).items())

    # Expand
    string = axiom
    for i in range(n):
        string = string.translate(table)
    return string
```

**Edit**:
I found a second approach that makes use of the built-in `map` function:

```
def fun2(n):
    axiom = 'L'
    rules = ['L=+RF-LFL-FR+','R=-LF+RFR+FL-']

    # Convert the rules into a translation table.
    rules = [ r.split('=') for r in rules ]
    table = dict(rules)
    lookup = lambda c: table[c] if c in table else c

    string = axiom
    for i in range(n):
        # Map
        string = map(lookup, string)
        # "Reduce": from list of strings to string
        string = ''.join(string)
    return string
```

**Timing**:
To check the runtime, I executed the candidates for `n=10`, which leads to a resulting string with about 3'500'000 characters. Your implementation (without the print ops of course) I named `fun3(n)`. The results I measured using the [`%timeit`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) command in `ipython`.

```
%timeit fun1(n=10)
10 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop

%timeit fun2(n=10)
10 loops, best of 3: 195 ms per loop

%timeit fun3(n=10)
10 loops, best of 3: 152 ms per loop
```

System: Python 3.5.2., MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7.

**Summary**: My first suggestion and your implementation perform about equally as fast, with a slight advantage on my version, particularly if it comes to readability. The `map` approach does not pay off.

I also tried a fourth version where the output array is preallocated, however the code was getting involved and python's memory allocation logic outperformed my preallocation approach clearly by a factor of 2 in runtime. I did not further investigate on this.

Comment: Thanks you for your help! I simply tested the code with a timer which gave me 150ms for both. Your testing is more accurate.